# cannot implicitly convert type int to bool

Tags: c#

I am creating a blackjack game and so far I have made a card class, deck class and shoe class. The card class works the deck class works, the shoe class works but I am still working on my hand class. I created a GetSum method to Return the sum of the cards in the hand by calling the SymbolToValue method to obtain the value for each card symbol and adding the values up. but my SymbolToValue method keeps giving me the error cannot implicitly convert type int to bool. I am not sure on how to fix this.

Any help or guidance in the right direction would be appreciated

Here's what I have for my hand class

```
class Hand
{
    const Int32 MAX_CARDS = 12;
    private Card[] _hand = new Card[MAX_CARDS];
    private Int32 _cardCount;
    public Hand()
    {
        _cardCount = 0;
    }
    public Int32 CardCount
    {
        get
        {

            return _cardCount;
        }
    }
    public void AddCard(Card card)
    {

        if (_cardCount < MAX_CARDS)
        {
            throw new Exception("Cannot of more than 12 cards in a hand");
        }
        else
        {
            _hand.Add(card);
            _cardCount++;


        }
    }
    public Card GetCard(Int32 cardIndex)
    {
        if (cardIndex >= _cardCount)
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid Entry");
        }
        else
        {
            return _hand[cardIndex];
        }
    }
    Int32[] cardValues = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10 };
    String[] cardSymbols = { "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K" };
    private Int32 SymbolToValue(String symbol)
    {
        int index = Array.IndexOf(cardSymbols, symbol);
        if (index != -1)
        {
            return cardValues[index];
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Value Not In Table");
        }
    }
   public Int32 GetSum()
    {
       String symbol;
       Int32 value;        
       for(value = 0; SymbolToValue(symbol); value++)
       {
           return value;
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't provided `SymbolToValue`. Presumably it returns an integer, while the second expression passed to `for` must be of boolean type. Not sure what to add here - it must be boolean, that's it. Not to say that your loop will not iterate more than once because of `return`.

Comment: try `for(value = 0; value <= SymbolToValue(symbol); value++)` in `GetSum` method.

Comment: @zerkms SymbolToValue is the next to last method

Comment: The second statement in `for` loop must be a boolean expression. When it evaluates to `false`, the loop terminates.

Comment: @aw04: oops, my ctrl-f-fu failed

Comment: @Igor Not to mention that the input to that function never changes and `symbol` isn't given a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to iterate over the hand to get the sum, try this for your GetSum:

```
public Int32 GetSum()
{
   int value = 0;

   for(int i = 0; i < _hand.length; i++)
   {
       value += SymbolToValue(_hand[i]);
   }

   return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the int32 function in a for loop where the condition should be present.

In your example, the for loop is expecting a boolean of true/false whether to execute the code in the loop or continue.

For your code to work, you would need a condition to be present.

Example;

```
for(value = 0; value > SymbolToValue(symbol); value++)
{
  //your stuff
}
```

If the value of the variable 'value' is the condition provided then continue, else loop until the condition is true. This is not your answer but will resolve the issue you are facing.